# How to use the Parse SDK with Xcode 7 and iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios9, xcode7

The `Parse SDK` has some libraries that IOS 9 doesn't support.

I hear it's because now IOS 9 has some new compression libraries and Parse still uses the old libraries, is there a way I can still import the old compression libraries so I can use Parse with IOS 9 applications?

> I'm specially looking to add  `wantibz.dylib`
>   `libsqlite3.dylib` to my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 7, both the libraries are available with different extensions namely `libz.tbd` and `libsqlite3.tbd`
The .tbd files are new "text-based stub libraries", that provide a much more compact version of the stub libraries for use in the SDK, and help to significantly reduce its download size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question (What compression libraries are you talking about? Where did you hear that? From whom?), but Parse has supported iOS 9 since [version 1.8.3 in early September](https://parse.com/docs/downloads). [Update your SDK](https://parse.com/).

> V1.8.3 — SEPTEMBER 11, 2015
>
> New
>
> Parse SDK now officially supports iOS 9, Xcode 7 and OS X 10.11.
>   PFQuery can now be used with the new Objective-C generics syntax.
>   Now shipping with backwards-compatible bitcode support on the Xcode 7 GM.

Comment: ibz.dylib
and libsqlite3.dylib, are not in IOS9 I want those 2 libraries in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to add Parse using Cocoapods by adding `pod 'Parse'` to my Podfile. I removed libz.tbd, libsqlite3.tbd, Parse.framework and Bolts.framework before running `pod install` and it worked.